# Resume not up-to-date for an application

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I have uploaded an updated version of my resume as PDF, but in the application after a while on the same day, the PDF attached to the application was not the updated one, but the older one.

At least this is what the confirmation mail says.

Comment: I assume you're speaking of Stack Overflow Jobs and your CV on here? Include some screenshots so we can better assist and tag this `Jobs` if that's the case?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you're right. Added the tag.

Comment: @MichaelDorner I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Can you send us an email to support@stackoverflow.com with details?